# C switch case label value already appeared

Tags: c, char, switch-statement, command-line-arguments, c-strings

Why IDE thinks there is an error ?

> "case label value has already appeared in this switch at line 9
> C/C++(1578)"

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {
        switch (*argv[i])
        {
            case 'drow': printf("drow detected");
            break;
            case 'drows': printf("drows detected"); //line 9
            break;
            case 'rows': printf("rows detected"); //error at the first apostrophe '
            break;
            default: printf("Unknown arg, skipping.");
            break;
        }  
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what do you expect to get with a form like `'drow'` ? for the compiler it is 'd' => you have two times `case 'd'`

Comment: You can't use strings in a `switch` statement. Putting strings in single quotes doesn't magically make it possible, it just turns the strings into `char`s; I'm surprised your compiler doesn't give you an error or at least a warning. Use a series of `if` statements using `strcmp` instead.

Comment: Anyway `*argv[i]` gives the first character of each argument string - not the string itself which is `argv[i]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a multibyte character constant as a label

```
case 'drow':
```

Its value is implementation defined of the type `int`.

The C Standard,  6.4.4.4 Character constants.

> The value of an integer character constant containing more than one
> character (e.g., 'ab'), or containing a character or escape sequence
> that does not map to a single-byte execution character, is
> implementation-defined.

So it seems the constants `'drow'` and `'drows'` have the same integer value.

The compiler could issue a message that the constant `'drows'` is too long for its type.

On the other hand, the expression used in the switch statement

```
switch (*argv[i])
```

is not a multibyte character. So in any case the switch statement does not make a sense.

Instead of the switch statement you could use if-else statements. For example

```
if ( strcmp( argv[i], "drow" ) == 0 )
{
    //...
}
else if ( strcmp( argv[i], "drows" ) == 0 )
{
    //...
}
else if ( strcmp( argv[i], "rows" ) == 0 )
{
    //...
}
else
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: Oh C, why didn't you just make this an error... is there ever a use for this?

Comment: @Thomas A character constant may be used as a label.

Comment: MSVC does throw an error: `error C2015: too many characters in constant`.